# In ReactJS, a simple inline styling not giving desired output

Tags: css, reactjs

Why Paragraph tag properties aren't applied to the text inside it? I am only getting the text in the output.

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {

  return (
    
    <p color='red' text-align='center' > Inside paragraph tag </p>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `style` attribute:

```
<p style={{ color: 'red', textAlign: 'center' }}>...</p>
```

See the docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

Answer (score 0):

The inline css in react are written as object. So we have have to use curly braces 2 times and also have to write css in camel-case.